# Use of the individual parts with Tkcalendar

Tags: python, python-3.x, tkinter, tkcalendar

My problem is that I want to use the individual parts from the calendar. That means, I would like to be able to use dd, mm and y individually. I decided to use the German spelling: dd.mm.y.

`datepicker = Calendar(root, selectmode="day", year=2021, month=1, day=1, date_pattern='ddmmy')`

In order to only filter out the day, I have so far proceeded as follows:

`birthday = str(datepicker.get_date())`
`bday = int(str(birthday)[:-6])`

But that's just a stopgap. How can I sort the day, month and year properly so that I can use the values ​​individually?

Thank you in advance for your answers, Best regards.

Comment: I dont think `tkcalendar` supports this. Though you can use `datepicker.get_date()` which return a `datetime` object, which you can play with later.

Comment: I don't really understand what you want to do. If you want to use separately the day, month and year, wouldn't it be easier to simply use 3 comboboxes or spinboxes?